# Equivalent of List Comprehension Using Map and Filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, map-function

I want to write this code using a map and/or a filter function. It returns the indices of items in a list provided the sum up to a target

I have used list comprehension for this but can't see how to get the second for loop into the map/filter function. I'm not sure about the syntax to use If I define my own function for the function argument of the map/filter function

```
num = [2,5,7,11,6,15,3,4]
tgt= 9
[num.index(x) for x in num for y in num if x + y == tgt]
```

Results:

```
[0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since both `filter` and `map` work over individual items in a sequence, you would have to view your logic from the perspective of each item in the list, rather than a combination of items, and that means you need to rephrase the expressions used in your list comprehension as functions of individual items. Instead of the filter condition `x + y == tgt`, therefore, it is beneficial to view it as `x == tgt - y`, where `y` also has to be an item in the `num` list, so that your list comprehension can be rewritten as:

```
[num.index(x) for x in num if x in {tgt - y for y in num}]
```

With this equivalent list comprehension, it then becomes clear that to implement the filter condition would need to make a set by mapping each item in `num` to its difference with `tgt`, which can be done with the `tgt.__sub__` method, and test each item `x` in `num` if it is a member of the set, which can be done with the set's `__contains__` method, and finally, map the filtered sequence to `num.index` to output the index of each matching item:

```
list(map(num.index, filter(set(map(tgt.__sub__, num)).__contains__, num)))
```

This returns:

```
[0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Use `set` instead of `list` here `list(map(tgt.__sub__, num))` for a better lookup

Comment: @blhsing Can you explain the inner workings of your solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The double loop can be code as a [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: num.index(x[0]), filter(lambda x: sum(x) == tgt, itertools.product(num, num))))
[0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7]
```

Lets chop the code:

```
filter(lambda x: sum(x) == tgt, itertools.product(num, num))
```

`itertools.product` returns an iterator of tuples whith the elements in num, being `(x, y)` similar to the nested loop you use.
over we filter which of those tuples summation is equal to `tgt`, using `sum` is the better choice here, but notice it would be the same as `x[0] + x[1]` (remember we are giving tuples like `(2, 2)` to that function).

Once we have that filtered we apply for each of those tuples that remain the function `num.index`, since we have tuples we only need to use one of the values, remember the first one matches the nested for loop `x` hence `num.index(x[0])`

Comment: Thanks can you explain the inner workings. Why do you use reduction functions ie( sum() and product() ) and num.index(x[0]) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this! You can use `itertools.product` to get the combinations of each. Then filter the list of combinations for items whose sum is `tgt`. Then map a lambda to those results to get the index of the first item in those combinations.

```
list(map(lambda x: num.index(x[0]), (filter(lambda x: sum(x) == tgt, itertools.product(num, repeat=2)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeatedly calling `num.index` is very inefficient. Each time you find a number that satisfies your condition, the call to `index` requires a sequential scan of the list.

Instead turn your loop over the indices in the list. Make the comparison by indexing the array (random access), which will be much more efficient.

As others have pointed out, you can use `itertools.product` but instead of the product of `num` with itself, do the self product of `range(len(num))`.

Using `map` and `filter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import product

res = map(
    itemgetter(0), 
    filter(
        lambda c: num[c[0]]+num[c[1]] == tgt, 
        product(range(len(num)),range(len(num)))
    )
)
print(list(res))
#[0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7]
```

The inner `filter` is filtering all pairs of numbers between 0 and the length of `num` minus one, for which the values at `num` at those corresponding indices is equal to the target. Since product returns a pair of indices and you are only interested in the first value, `map` the result of the `filter` with `itemgetter(0)` to get the first element.

More compactly as a list comprehension:

```
[i for i, j in product(range(len(num)), range(len(num))) if num[i] + num[j] == tgt]
```